# INSERT INTO MySQL statement error C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to use a parameterised insert into sql query. I have used this code however I am getting a 'fatal' error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Fatal error encountered during command execution.

C# Code:

```
        using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=project;username=root;password=***;"))
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO test_results (test_results) VALUES (@testResults);");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test_results", correctAnswers);
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
        }
```

Line:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am trying to add the number of questions (correctAnswers) the user got correct into the field "test_results)

EDIT:

```
 int topicID = dataGridViewRow.Cells["topicID"].Value.ToString();
```

> cannot implicitly convert type string to int

I know why I am getting this but I don't know what I should do.

Comment: I suspect you'll find there's more information in the exception if you look closely, and I suspect it's because you've called the parameter `@testResults` in the statement, and `@test_results` when populating it.

Comment: so how should I amend my code to fix this?

Comment: Um, use a consistent name? Read my comment carefully, read your code carefully, and carefully consider how parameterized SQL works. How do you expect it to work if the name in your SQL doesn't match the name of the parameter in your `Parameters` collection?

Comment: What is the type of `correctAnswers` ?

Comment: SPELLING MISTAKE. In query it is testResults and in adding value it is @test_results

Comment: its working now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please ask *one* question post. Don't edit a question once it's been solved to then ask the next one, and so on. That's not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @JonSkeet ..ok thanks for letting me know. I was wondering why I got -1 on all my posts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter name has to be the same when you set value for that parameter.

```
     using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=project;username=root;password=***;"))
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO test_results (test_results) VALUES (@testResults);");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testResults", correctAnswers);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
    }
```

Comment: @Huesyn Alizada can you check bottom of the question I edited :) plz

Comment: You should convert it to int. Change your code like that  `int topicID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewRow.Cells["topicID"].Value);
`

Comment: In future, questions that are basically due to a typo are best closed as "Off-topic: this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."